# Regarding Propagation.NEVER transactions in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I have a question regarding `Propagation.NEVER` usage with `@Transactional` in the service layer. I use this on a method of service layer which calls DAO layer method which calls `session.save()` method of Hibernate.

As `NEVER` means no transaction should be present, it is executing the service layer method without any error because as there is no session. But this also means `save()` method which calls in service layer doesn't have a transaction, right? And if it doesn't have a transaction, it should throw an error, right? Can you please correct me why the record is getting stored even without transaction.

Service layer code is as follows:

```
@Service("userSer")
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NEVER)
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        userDao.create(user);
    }   
}
```

DAO layer code is as follows:

```
@Repository("user")
public class HibernateUserDao implements UserDao{
    
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    public Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
    
    public User create(User user) {
        currentSession().save(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

And I am testing from a main method as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring-hibernate-idol.xml");
    UserService service = (UserService)context.getBean("userSer");
    User u1 = new User();
    u1.setPassword("bsk5");
    service.saveUser(u1);
    System.out.println("Record created finally if this line is printed");
}
```

Can you please help me out in understanding this.

Comment: Your test and understanding is wrong. Nothing will be saved because there is no transaction. There would be an exception if there already was a transaction and you would call the method annotated with a propagation level of NEVER. To test, call save, then query the database and you will find nothing is there.

Comment: Hi @Deinum, First of all thank you so much for the response. But when i run the above code, there were no exceptions and database has been updated with a record successfully. Even i thought like you but when it got saved, I was thrilled and asked this question in the forum. Can you please have a look at it again and respong accordingly

Comment: Which database are you using and add the configuration (`spring-hibernate-idol.xml`).

Comment: Hi @Deinum I am using Oracle Express Edition(Oracle XE) as a database.   and what is the need for spring-hibernate-idol.xml?

Comment: To see your configuration...